# How to input php as url in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to get the post thumbnail by using php in the script.

Example: (I don't know if this makes any sense)

```
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '' ); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var conf = {
          poster: "<?php echo $url ?>"
          };
```

Comment: Is this not working in some way?  Do you just need the semi-colon at the end of that line of PHP?

Comment: No, I don't. Sorry about that. I fixed it.

Comment: You put the semicolon in the wrong place, it belongs after `echo $url`, then all you need to do is use `conf.poster` somewhere in your javascript

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that exactly?

Comment: @John: So what exactly is the problem?  Are you getting an error of some kind?  What isn't working and how is it failing?

Comment: It's not getting the poster (post thumbnail). It's not doing anything

Comment: What *are* you getting?  What is the resulting client-side code from this?  Are there any errors in the browser's development console?  Any errors in the PHP logs?  What happens if you *do* add the semi-colon at the end of the line of PHP code?  (JavaScript has implicit semi-colons at the end of a block of code, but I don't know if PHP does.)

Comment: It's basically ignoring the command but when I had it as >> poster: "url". It works, but I want it to get different post image every time.

Comment: "It's basically ignoring the command" doesn't tell us anything.  Use your browser's debugging tools.  What is the actual JavaScript code that gets generated?  How does it actually fail?

Answer (score 0):

your code seems correct!

```
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
```

Im using the same for the jwplayer.

But `<?php echo $url ?>` is wrong use `<?php echo $url; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Dig down about [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) function in wordpress It Localizes a registered script with data for a JavaScript variable.